# openmp in mex : stackoverflow error

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, mex

i have got the following fraction of code that getting me the stack overflow error

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(Mo1, Mo2, sum_normalized_p_gn, Data, Mean_Out,Covar_Out,Prior_Out, det) private(i)  num_threads( number_threads )  
{  

        //every thread has a new copy  
        double* normalized_p_gn = (double*)malloc(NMIX*sizeof(double));   
        #pragma omp critical  
        {
            int id =  omp_get_thread_num();
            int threads = omp_get_num_threads();
            mexEvalString("drawnow");  
        }  

        #pragma omp for
        //some parallel process.....

}
```

the variables declared in the shared are created by malloc. and they consumes with large amount of memory

there are 2 questions regarding to the above code.
1) why this would generate the stack overflow error( i.e. segmentation fault) before it goes into the parallel for loop? it works fine when it runs in the sequential mode....
2) am i right to dynamic allocate memory for each thread like "normalized_p_gn" above?

Regards
Edwin

Comment: When/where are you freeing the dynamically allocated memory ?

Answer (score 2):

In place of `malloc`, use `mxMalloc` in mex files (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/apiref/mxmalloc.html)). Don't forget to `mxFree` when you're finished with the memory.

Comment: @Edwin: Yes, I saw that from your OP. `malloc` often works OK in mex files, but it is unreliable: I've found I run the same code and it works sometimes and not others. I'd change to `mxMalloc` and test it. For other problems it'd be good to see a larger code segment, including the free.

Comment: mxMalloc is not thread safe, as are all mx* commands and should be avoided in the parallel region.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility which we can't exclude, your code snippet doesn't reveal any numbers, is that you are simply trying to allocate too much memory when you run this in parallel.  If you can confirm that this is not your problem, comment or edit your question and I'll take another look.